# Getting date and time from mysql to output into html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have been working on this thing for awhile now and cannot figure it out.

What I want to do is run a function that will call all my records for a specific date and output them in an html table.

I can do it by running the query inside the loop but I'm wanting to learn how to use arrays to accomplish this.

```
function getAll(){
    include('inc/connect.php');
    $a = $data->query("SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE active = 'true'");
    $args = array();

    while($b = $a->fetch_array()){
        $t1 = strtotime($b["endtime"]);
        $t2 = strtotime($b["starttime"]);
        $diff = $t1 - $t2;
        $hours = $diff / ( 60 * 60 );
        $args[] = array('start' => $b["starttime"],
                        'end' => $b["endtime"],
                        'span' => $hours
                    );
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Above is the function that I run to get all and return the arrays but I'm very new to arrays and have no idea how to run them against the below.

```
$interval = 1800; // Interval in seconds

$date_first     = "02-09-2013 00:00:00";
$date_second    = "03-09-2013 00:00:00";

$time_first     = strtotime($date_first);
$time_second    = strtotime($date_second);

$go = getAll();

for ($i = $time_first; $i <= $time_second; $i += $interval){
    $timeOut = date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime("+30 minutes", $i));

    //////I WOULD LIKE TO RUN THE ARRAY CALLED BY $go HERE TO SEE IF start == $timeOut/////
}
```

I'm try to get the following results onto the html table as a td colspan to represent the time. Thanks in advance for the help.

[image]

Comment: why are you not filtering the result in MySQL directly?

Comment: Im try to utilize one query to get the results returned via array, instead of querying the DB 24 times.

Comment: You don't have to query 24 times, just add to the where clause: `WHERE active = true and starttime >= '2013-09-03 00:00:00' and endtime <= '2013-09-03 00:00:00'`

Comment: Ok I understand the query limiter but the problem is not the query, it's  my understanding of using the returned array to process against $timeOut inside the for loop to output the td colspan.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is not the right way to process this data, but if you just want to play with arrays,

try this:

```
$interval = 1800; // Interval in seconds

$date_first     = "02-09-2013 00:00:00";
$date_second    = "03-09-2013 00:00:00";

$time_first     = strtotime($date_first);
$time_second    = strtotime($date_second);

$go = getAll();


for ($i = $time_first; $i <= $time_second; $i += $interval){
    $timeOut = date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime("+30 minutes", $i));

    //////I WOULD LIKE TO RUN THE ARRAY CALLED BY $go HERE TO SEE IF start == $timeOut/////

    // To process all entries in an array use the FOREACH verb
    // foreach entry in the array it will return the array key and the value associated with that key
    // as 2 new variables. As the value is another array I have called it $innerArray

    foreach ( $go as $key => $innerArray ) {

        if ( $innerArray['start'] == $timeout ) {

            $msg = 'timeout = ' . $timeout;
            $msg .= ' $go key = ' . $key;
            $msg .= ' innerArrays[start] = ' . innerArrays['start'];
            $msg .= ' innerArrays[end] = ' . innerArrays['end'];
            $msg .= ' innerArrays[span] = ' . innerArrays['span'];
            // not sure it you are using the CLI or Web Server so feel free to change this to something more simple
            $msg .= strtoupper(PHP_SAPI) == 'CLI' ? PHP_EOL : '<br>';

            echo $msg;
        }
    }
}
```